# express.js 4 has broken request.on('data') triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm hoping someone can either find what I'm doing wrong or can verify what I'm discovering to be true.

On a post to a node.js server there just isn't any way in the world `request.on('data')` works.
Body-parser/json just isn't setting up express correctly or express isn't doing it's job, or both.

Following are two paired projects, one server & one client to send a post to the server.  Both are in node.js.  The server includes express & `body-parser`

This is server side:

```
/* Used to start Node
var debug = require('debug')('ExpressApp1');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
*/

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var fRawBody = function (req, res, buf, encoding) {
    if (buf && buf.length) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
        console.log("buf", req.rawBody);
    }
}

app.use('/', bodyParser.json({ verify: fRawBody }));

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("content-type", req.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('data: chunk', chunk);
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        req.rawBody = data;
        console.log("raw", req.rawBody);
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});


module.exports = app;
```

--- end of app.js ----

This is the client.

Client side response.on('data') works fine.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "1337",
    "path": "/",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "44e8850a-7a9d-42ce-fbbf-02ac3e6e051b"
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
        process.exit();
    });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ data: { theGreatest: 'SMT' } }));
req.end();
```

I'm hoping someone can either find what I'm doing wrong or can verify what I'm finding out to be true.

Node.js 4.2.4 (client & server)

Express  4.9.8 (server)

Body-Parser.js 1.8.4 (server)

Thanks.

Comment: The `bodyParser()` middleware you already have installed will already read the entire stream and put the parsed results into `req.body`.  So there is no data on the incoming stream left to read.  So, for a request that matches the bodyParser type you have installed (which in your case is JSON), the middleware will already read the contents of the incoming stream.

Comment: Okay. So how do I get to either CHUNK or trigger req.on('data') so I can get to CHUNk?  More than anything else I'm reading, your explanation makes sense, but I still have a problem to fix

Comment: Well. You either want that Middleware to do its thing or you don't. Decide. If you don't want it in force and want to read the data yourself then don't use the Middleware. But since the Middleware is only active for Json data, I don't understand why you would need to read the Json yourself when the Middleware already did it for you.

Comment: So, really my question to you is, why are you trying to read the body yourself when the middleware has already read and parsed it for you and conveniently placed the parsed results in `req.body` for you to use?

Comment: A) I don't know how to read the body without the middleware and B) with the middleware I'm completely cock blocked.  I need buffer or chunk or whatever.  But ever which way I've turned node/express f's me

Comment: PS. The are a great ton of others on the inet, including this forum, who have to resort to the same as I am.  If ever that spoke to a design flaw, opportunity then I don't know what else does

Comment: Why are you using the middleware if you don't want to use it's results?  Remove the body-parser middleware and you will get the chunks.  But, it seems silly to remove code that already parses your JSON for you.  As it stands now, it makes no sense what you are trying to do.  You have an already parsed result right in front of you in `req.body` and you're complaining about why you can't manually reread it and then parse it yourself!

Comment: You do not need body-parser in order to read the body manually.  Remove it and your code will work.  The whole point of the body-parser middleware is to read the body FOR YOU so you don't have to.  You cannot do both.  It feels like you copied some code that has the body-parser middleware in it, but have no idea what it does or why its there and now you're surprised that it is doing the job it is supposed to do.

Comment: "no idea what it does" it where you are wrong. After 10 hours of multiple efforts I've come to believe there is a flaw somewhere in this platform.  It is just JavaScript. But for the designers ability of the overwhelming number of module options, it isn't that complex.  Taken a lot from others is where you are correct.  In fact, of all my effort, code, reading, and documentation, I don't recall anyone suggesting I can do as you are here.  I hope you are right.

Comment: But if removing body-parser alone doesn't enable access to triggering .on('data') so I can consistently get chunk, then how do I access the body/data as one constitent stream?  How do I, with a high degree of reliability get body as an array of byte into a variable?  Because it seems absolutely everywhere I turn the suggestion is req.on('data') to get chunk.  Which only works in my platform Ina Avery narrow configuration of posting requests.

Comment: PS. Thanks for sticking with this.  I'll try what you suggest and let you know tomorrow

Comment: I guess I need to give up.  The body of the POST has already been read, already been parse and the result is in `req.body`.  It is put there by the body-parser middleware.  You do NOT need to read it yourself.  You won't explain to me WHY you think you need to read it again so I can't solve a problem you won't explain.  Why are you trying to read something that has ALREADY BEEN READ?  You simply don't need to do that.

Comment: If, for some reason, you don't want that middleware to apply to a specific route, then configure the middleware differently so it only applies to some routes.  Otherwise, just use the results of the middleware since all the reading and parsing work has already been done for you.  Your client code is sending JSON and you have configured the body-parser middleware to read that JSON for you.  That's what it's doing.  It has already been read and the results have been stored for you in `req.body`.  You do NOT need to read it again.  I'm done until you can explain why you need to read it again.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm back on this this morning. Because pre-BodyParser is an string. And post-BodyParser is an object. I CAN'T use the object for something I have to do. And I can't talk at in depth about things because ... well I just can't ... BUT I DO THANK YOU. You have gotten me to remove BodyParser and now get to the what I was looking for, so simple in fact it is shocking. And to simply get back to the objectified version of the string a I can make a simple call to JSON.parse() for myself. That isn't something I need another module to do for me. Following next is some food for thought.

Comment: @jfriend00 There are A LOT of people out there needed the same as I am. That is a little bit by analogy but after hours and hours of reading posts after post after post I feel confident in that claim. It would be great if BodyParser by design also gave up a req.on() & the chunk. If node.js is built to do so then so can BodyParser. It is only an issue of design by the men who designed it. And a great many people would be relieved and wouldn't have to work around BodyParser as I now understand I will have to because the current design of BodyParser just isn't what it need to be for this project.

Comment: @jfriend00 Again THANK YOU. Your help is highly valued.

Comment: JSON.stringify() to convert said object back to json for that one specific case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take my comments and form them into an answer.

The `body-parser` middleware will read the entire body of the post, parse it and put the parsed result into `req.body`.  That means that if that middleware is active for a particular route and the content-type matches what the middleware is looking for, then it will already have read the stream and when express gets to your route handler, there is no more stream to read and thus you will not get any 'data' events.

So, if what you're after is the raw, unparsed body as a string, you have several options:

1. You can remove the body-parser middleware from your route so it will not read the stream and then you can read the stream yourself in your route handler.  This can either be done by removing the body-parser middleware entirely or specifying it in a way that it will not be in effect for the particular routes that you want to skip it on.
2. You can use `bodyParser.text()` instead of `bodyParser.json()` and the middleware will read the body as text so when express calls your route handler, the body has already been read as text and placed into `req.body` as plain text.
3. You use the already parsed `req.body` instead of reading and parsing the JSON yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is about a minimal as I can make it.  This is without the use of Body-Parser.
The confusion creeps in because Body-Parser completely over takes the 'req' variable.

Thanks & credit to jfriend00

-- server side awaiting the post --

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.sendStatus(200) });
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("-----");
        console.log("hdr", req.headers['content-type']);
        console.log("raw", JSON.parse(data));
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
module.exports = app;
```

-- client side sending to the server ---

```
var http = require("http");
var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "1337",
    "path": "/",
    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" }
};
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        process.exit();
});
req.write(JSON.stringify( { theGreatestHit: 'ChuckBerry Maybellene' }));
req.end();
```